# GCC optimization settings for test code

Tags: gcc, optimization, assembly

I like to read the ASM output of small test programs, but if I turn on even -O, it hardcodes some stack declared constants and somewhat breaks the objdump output.
What settings do I need to be able to look at the ASM as if I used dynamic memory and not a constant?

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -S -fverbose-asm your-file.c -o out-asm-file.s`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use constants. Read the values from the command line or from a disk file.

otherwise, if you have code like `int value = 3` the compiler will *always* replace value with 3 whenever it can.

Comment: I thought I would do it this way, but maybe you are right, it would mirror the real usage better.  But for arguments sake...